# Application api - Generic method for touch event in the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

Is there is any event available in Applicaiton api to capture the touch event in the screen. I want some generic method for capture the touchevent for the entire screen (which means menu, activity, keypad, DialogFragment etc..).

I know that we can use onUserIteraction() mtd for activity and onMenuItemClick() for menu etc, but i need some generic method to control all the item in the screen.

Thanks
Mindus

Comment: use view's onTouchListener() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: This i tried already, it's not working.

Comment: post what you have tried so far